# jquery validation max not working

Tags: jquery, validation, max

Jquery validation max does not seem to work when I input the a number and its first digit is less than the first digit of the max

Example:

```
 $("#formPaymentModal").validate({
        rules: {
            payment: { 
                digits: true,
                min: 1,
                max: 400
            }
        }
 });
```

When I type 1000, 2000, 3000+, there are no errors. but when I type 4000, 5000 and so on an error shows up.

Here's the HTML: I'm using Laravel

```
<div class="form-group">
           <label for="payment" class="col-sm-3 control-label">Payment</label>
           <div class="col-sm-9">
                <div class="input-group">
                    <span class="input-group-addon">&#8369;</span>
                    {{ Form::text('payment', '', array('class' => 'form-control', 'id' => 'payment', 'placeholder' => '', 'required')); }}
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

i have created example for you on jsfiddle:-

```
$("#myform").validate({
    rules: {
        field: {
            required: true,

            digits: true,
            min: 1,
            max: 400
        }
    }
});
```

click here:http://jsfiddle.net/TnbYm/18/

thanks